# Not able to use ng-lodash with restangular

Tags: angularjs, lodash, restangular

I am trying to use *ngLodash* with *restangular* but i m not able to succeed. Below is the error:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=portalApp&p1=Error%…A7080%2FNetworkInsight%2Fstatic%2Fjs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A381)

I am able to use *restangular* with *lodash* and underscore successfully .

Below is the code:

angular.module('testApp', ['ngLodash', 'restangular']);

The code does not run when i include the below files

ng-lodash.min.js and restangular.min.js

but when i add underscore-min.js the code starts running successfully.

Restangular needs underscore or lodash to run. But restangular is not able to find lodash  when we include it as angularized lodash(ngLoad)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show the code that is creating the error?

Comment: I have edited my original post

Comment: Did anyone got a chance to look at it?